# Share properties without inheritance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using engine Unity, where base class for almost all scripts have to derive from MonoBehaviour. I created my own wrapper class that is deriving from MonoBehaviour called CMonoBehaviour which contains some my helper functions that I am using almost everywhere. But now I am facing problem, that SOMETIME I dont want to derive from MonoBehavuour but ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass (class, that is deriving from MonoBehaviour too but is allso implementing some aditional funcionality - just like my wrapper). Here is example what I want to archive.

edit: I forgot to mention that ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass is packed in dll, which means that I cant modify it in any way

```
 // This is what I have
public class CMonoBehavour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int SomeHelperProperty1 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty2 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty3 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty4 { get; private set; }
}

public class ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int SomeHelperProperty5 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty6 { get; private set; }
}

// My problem :

public class ExampleUseage1 : CMonoBehavour
{
    // here I have to copypaste content of ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass because I cust cannot derive from two classes
}

public class ExampleUseage2 : ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass
{
    // here I have to copypaste content of CMonoBehavour because I cust cannot derive from two classes
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to rethink your architecture.
It seems that you are overly dependent on inheritance to provide functionality.

There are a bunch of ways to restructure your approach, such as:

- use extension methods to provide functionality (interface extension methods are a good idea)
- use composition
- use interfaces + composition => you can wrap composition in re-implemented properties that will just pass the calls to the internal object.

**A composite/wrapper solution:**

```
    public class CMonoBehavour : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int SomeHelperProperty1 { get; private set; }
        public int SomeHelperProperty2 { get; private set; }
        public int SomeHelperProperty3 { get; private set; }
        public int SomeHelperProperty4 { get; private set; }
    }

    public class ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int SomeHelperProperty5 { get; private set; }
        public int SomeHelperProperty6 { get; private set; }
    }

    //COMPOSITE SOLUTION

    public class CompositeMonoBehaviour : CMonoBehaviour
    {
        private ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass _thirdParty;

        public int SomeHelperProperty5 { get{ return _thirdParty.SomeHelperProperty5; } }
        public int SomeHelperProperty6 { get{ return _thirdParty.SomeHelperProperty6; } }
    }

    public class ExampleUseage1 : CompositeMonoBehaviour
    {
          //you have all your properties, great news!
    }

    public class ExampleUseage2 : CompositeMonoBehaviour
    {
        //you have all your properties, great news!
    }
```

Bear in mind, that Unity has an entity-component system at the core of it's GameObject design. Over-doing inheritance is:

- bad design in general
- fighting the framework, which is an exercise in futility

Comment: Yes I affraid, that there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

You can do partial inheritance and share only the properties you need. Something like that:

```
public class CMonoBehavour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int SomeHelperProperty1 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty2 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty3 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty4 { get; private set; }
}

public class ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass : CMonoBehavour
{
    public int SomeHelperProperty5 { get; private set; }
    public int SomeHelperProperty6 { get; private set; }
}


//The first class have 4 properties
public class ExampleUseage1 : CMonoBehavour
{

}
    //The first class have 6 properties
public class ExampleUseage2 : ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass
{

}
```

Comment: Yes but problem is that ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass is packent in dll and I cant modify it...

Comment: is CMonoBehavour yours?

Comment: Yes but is shared between multiple projects (so it cant inherit from ThirtPartyLibraryWrapperClass)

Answer (score -1):

## Interface Magic

`CMonoBehavour` (uh, `CMonoBehaviour` because there's an `i` in "Behaviour") should be an *interface* in this case.

```
public interface CMonoBehaviour
{
    int SomeHelperProperty1 { get; }
    int SomeHelperProperty2 { get; }
    int SomeHelperProperty3 { get; }
    int SomeHelperProperty4 { get; }
}
```

Note that while there is no `set` defined, it is *perfectly legal* for the interface-implementer to implement a private set.  The interface is only a listing of all *public* properties and methods.

e.g:

```
public class Something : MonoBehaviour,CMonoBehaviour
{
    private int a;
    public int SomeHelperProperty1 {
        get {
            return a;
        }

        private set  {
            a = value;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Although now its an interface, maybe we should rename it to indicate that: `IMonoBehaviour` or possibly `IBehaviourExtensions` or `IBehaviourAdditions` or `IBaseBehaviour`.  Naming it "MonoBehaviour" isn't really helpful or indicative about what this class/interface is for or does.